# Customizing iPhone app taskbar

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I thought that it was not allowed to customize the taskbar on the iPhone.  However, I noticed this app called iHandy Tip Calculator which replaces the battery icon with a fast switch icon, that pops up a view as shown.  How is this allowed, and if so how can I be doing something different?

[image]

Comment: I don't think that screenshot you've provided is for iHandy Tip Calculator (well... it's the tip calculator in the background), but what's in the foreground appears to be from some product called "Quick Switch".

Comment: I think this is a screenshot from a jailbroken iPhone device.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Check out the free version of the app and pay attention to the battery icon, it changes to the quick switch

Comment: @basvk No it is from my iPhone, check out the free version of the app, and see for yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run the app on an iPad, you'll see, how they do it: they are overlaying the normal status bar. Also note, that the screenshots in the app store don't show this feature. I assume, they were fearing to get rejected and disabled the overlay for the screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create your own statusbar and "simulate" the network status and battery life etc in a 'full-screen' app. But apple doesn't allow it, but this might be one that 'slipped through' just like Gaz_Edge said.

Answer (score 2):

Apps from this developer iHandy incorporate this into the status bar, but I've never seen another company do this. I am surprised that the status bar is able to be modified in this way in any event.

My question on apple.stackexchange is posted over here:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71969/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-status-bar-icon

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. You are not suppose to be able to modify the 'springboard'. Apple normally refuse apps that do anything that modifies it. Maybe this one slipped  through the net?

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the latest version of iHandy Level (version 1.62.0) on an iPhone 5 running iOS 6 but don't see the icon (it's within the app rather than in the status bar). (And the status bar is hidden.)

I was curious to see if they actually hid the status bar and created their own custom status bar. **If that was the case, you'd be able to tell because when you swipe down from the top for notification center, it would first show a little tab and then you'd have to swipe again to pull down the menu.**

Guessing maybe they removed this functionality at Apple's request.

**If anyone still has a version that shows it, please let us know if it shows the tab when you swipe for notification center.** If not, they likely found some private api to allow them to replace the battery icon (which would be interesting).

Comment: Just downloaded the tip calculator--it does show the icon. And it does work when you click on it, and notification center pulls down right away so they're not hiding the replicating the menubar. They must have figured out a way to draw over it and detect taps on it. I'd be interested to see if anyone finds a concrete way (in code) to achieve the same result.

Comment: I wouldn't bother, it will probably lead to your app being rejected anyway